# Decoding a single column in a CSV file using python 3 Base64

Tags: python, csv, pandas, base64

I am very new and inexperienced to Python but I hope someone can help me with this. I didn't find any (understandable?) answers on google.

I have a large (10gb) CSV file that contains multiple columns. All columns are "normal" human readable text except for one column. This column is binary. I would like to decode this and write it the decoded data back into the CSV file.

This is what I got so far, but I have a feeling I'm way off. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import base64
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', delimiter=';',
                 usecols=[3], dtype=object, header=None,)
decoded_binary_data = base64.b64decode(df)

print(decoded_binary_data)
```

sample of CSV:

```
"5f8ebfd8-7d12-4659-a416-e5dcbe056d0a";"6";"1";**ez??R?+??a)???
Cs**;0;0;0;74;1720;
```

- EDIT cleaned up the CSV file a bit.
- EDIT added sample dataframe

sample of dataframe:

```
0                                       ez??R?+??a)???Cs
1                       B?t?a?h?kwd?W-]\???fc?m[m?A}??? 
2                       ?eE????3r??c??T????fc?m[m?A}??? 
3                       ?eE????3r??c??T????fc?m[m?A}??? 
4                       ?eE????3r??c??T????fc?m[m?A}??? 
5                       B?t?a?h?kwd?W-]\???fc?m[m?A}???
```

Comment: can you post a small sample data set (with some encoded data)?

Comment: it doesn't look like a healthy CSV file - it has different # of columns in different rows

Comment: Where does the csv file come from?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to post it in the correct format, but the sample provided is a single row.

Comment: Someone called 'cpcloud' offers an approach at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6305.

Comment: @BillBell Thanks for that, I'll dive into it. Still have a lot to learn.

Comment: I've tried decoding `str = 'B?t?a?h?kwd?W-]\???fc?m[m?A}???'` with each of the methods available in `base64`, the module that comes with Py3.4. None of them work. I was suspicious because I would have expected a preponderance of alphanumeric characters in those strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
bs64 = lambda x: base64.b64decode(x)

decoded_binary_data = df['col_name'].apply(bs64)
```

See this page:
https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_dataframes.html